# Spring MVC how to display static pages

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using spring 2.5.6 with MVC.  The new site I am working on has static pages, such as home page, simple landing pages etc, along with other CRUD type of pages.

I am having a heck of a time to get the two to work together, so obviously I am doing something very wrong cause it can not be that hard.

So first I started off with the following as an example:

```
<bean name="/account-landing.html" class="com.account.web.AccountLandingController">
  <property name="commandClass" value="com.account.web.AccountLandingCommand"/>
  <property name="formView" value="account-landing"/>
  <property name="successView" value="account-landing"/>
</bean>
```

and several others and that worked fine.

Now, I want to introduce the static pages

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mapping">
    <props>
      <prop key="/home.html">urlFilenameViewController</prop>
      [snip]
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="urlFilenameViewController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController"/>
```

and there is a view resolver.  All the pages in my application have been converted over to .jsp.

I have looked over the documentation but still not clicking.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your htmls are getting resolved correctly? after converting to jsp, have you changed your dispatcher servlet to intercept both html and jsp? And by the way - you really don't need to route static content through Spring Dispatcher Servlet. That's an overhead. Can you paste your servlet config here?

Answer (score 1):

if you want static pages don't map. put it in a separate folder and access it. after all this is a web app

like `http://<ip>/appname/htmls/test.html`